# vba skip nonexisting elements from getElementsByTagName() to prevent error

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, error-handling, getelementsbytagname

I have this:

```
<table class="series">
    <tr><th>1.</th><td><div><a href="?test1">Link1</a></div></td></tr>
    <tr><th>2.</th><td><b>Link2</b></td></tr>
    <tr><th>3.</th><td><div><a href="?test3">Link3</a></div></td></tr>
</table>
```

and I need to loop through each  in order to find where there is NO url link.

```
dim serieTest as Object
If element.tagName = "TABLE" And element.className = "series" Then
    Set data_series = element.getElementsByTagName("td")
    For Each serie In data_series
        Set serieTest = serie.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href
        If Not (serieTest Is Nothing) Then
            debug.print "link found!"
        Else
            debug.print "link NOT found!"
        End If
        Set serieTest = Nothing
    Next
    Set data_series = Nothing
End If
```

but im having error:

```
Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set
```

on line with:

```
Set serieTest = serie.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href
```

any idea how to prevent this?
I have tried just to put On Error Resume Next above the errorline, but then it just goes straightly to "ELSE" as it doesnt asign anything so therefore "serie" i always null.

Comment: yes, of course, all of them will be properly closed and correct answer marked. Im working on huge project, so some questions seems similar or same, however they all have different application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get an href value it is a string not an object. You could re-write your code as follows (though I would refer you to my prior answer to one of your questions which handles this scenario better using a helper function and select case):

```
Dim serieTest As Object, serieHref As String

If element.tagName = "TABLE" And element.className = "series" Then

    Set data_series = element.getElementsByTagName("td")

    For Each serie In data_series

        serieHref = "link NOT found!"

        If serie.getElementsByTagName("a").Length > 0 Then

            Set serieTest = serie.getElementsByTagName("a")(0) 'object

            If serieTest.hasattribute("href") Then
                serieHref = serieTest.href
                Debug.Print "link found!"
            End If
        End If
        Debug.Print serieHref
    Next

End If
```